# Localizing "$|"

Tags: perl

Can I use both ways to localize `$|` or should I use one in favor of the other?

Way 1: backup old value of `$|` in "_init_scr" and set back `$|` to the old value when "_end_win" is called.
Way 2: calling `local $| = 1` after "_init_scr" is called.

```
package Package_name

# ...

sub _init_scr {
    my ( $arg ) = @_;
    $arg->{old_handle} = select( $arg->{handle_out} );
    #$arg->{backup_flush} = $|; # way 1
    $| = 1;
    # ...
}

sub _end_win {
    my ( $arg ) = @_;
    # ...
    #$| = $arg->{backup_flush}; # way 1
    select( $arg->{old_handle} );
}

sub choose {
    my $arg = ...;
    # ...
    _init_scr( $arg );
    # way 2 - instead of setting `$|` in "_init_scr" set it here:
    #local $| = 1;
    # ...
    while ( 1 ) {
        my $c = _getch( $arg );
        # ...;
        given ( $c ) {
            # ...
            when ( $c == CONTROL_C ) {
                _end_win( $arg );
                print "^C";
                kill( 'INT', $$ );
                return;
            }
            when ( $c == KEY_ENTER ) {
                # ...
                _end_win( $arg );
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$|` would have been a good fit in the "_init_scr" because there is all initialization stuff.

Comment: I have to remind me to keep the `local $| = 1` after "_init_scr".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `local`. That way, `$|` is restored no matter how the sub is exited (exception, early `return`, etc).

By the way, you could use `select()->flush;` instead of toggling `$|` back and forth.

```
use IO::Handle qw( );  # Required in older versions of Perl.
print "^C";
select()->flush();
```

---

That said, the advantage of `local $|` is gone since you need to call `_end_win` to clean up anyway. So let's get rid of the need for `_end_win`.

```
use Sub::ScopeFinalizer qw( scope_finalizer );

sub _local_scr {
    my ( $arg ) = @_;
    my $old_autoflush = $|;
    my $old_handle = select( $arg->{handle_out} );
    $| = 1;

    return scope_finalizer {
       $| = $old_autoflush;
       select($old_handle);
    };
}

sub choose {
    my $arg = ...;

    my $guard = _local_scr( $arg );

    while ( 1 ) {
        ...
                print "^C";
                kill( 'INT', $$ );
                return;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be an early `return`?

Comment: @sid_com, `return` before the end of the sub.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to localize the value, just use `local`.  It will handle restoring the original value when the scope where it was localized is exited without any additional effort (or chance for mistakes) on your part.

Answer (score 2):

Third way:

```
use IO::Handle;
# ...
$arg->{handle_out}->autoflush(1);
# ...
$arg->{handle_out}->autoflush(0);
```

There are various other convenient methods available in IO::Handle.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `local $| = 1;`, as this is the idiomatic Perl way of doing this.  It's  simpler than keeping track of the value in another variable.

Use an extra set of braces (if needed) to create a scope so that it only applies to the part of the program that should have it set.

```
{
   #Buffering is turned off only in here.
   local $| = 1;
   unbuffered_commands();
}

buffered_commands();
```

Comment: "Because it's idomatic" assumes everything else is equal, and it's not. Because it's idomatic is not the reason to use `local`.

Comment: @ikegami, I gave two reasons: 1) idiomatic, 2) simpler.